# Отображение результата PartialView происходит не сразу

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

Добрый день, уважаемые форумчане, перейду сразу к сути проблемы.
Имеется представление, внутри которого есть блок `div`, куда я отображаю результат `PartialView`. Вот как выглядит `View`:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(T4.Admin.PlanningInformationImport(), 
new AjaxOptions{
HttpMethod = "POST",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
UpdateTargetId = "planning-import-history-block",
OnBegin = "AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOn",
OnComplete = "AjaxAbsoluteLoaderOff"
}, 
new
{
    @class = "form-horizontal",
    enctype = "multipart/form-data"
}))
{
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Дата</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" id="filter-date" name="filterDate" value="@Model.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Заливка домов</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label">Файл</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="import-file" type="file" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" name="fileUpload" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <button id="downloadPremises" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" >Загрузить дома</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<fieldset>
    <legend>История</legend>
    <div class="row" id="planning-import-history-block">

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Ничего безобидного, все просто. Вот как выглядит метод контроллера, который меняет возвращает уже мне `PartialView`:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual PartialViewResult PlanningInformationImport(HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload, DateTime filterDate, FormCollection formData)
{
    string message = null;
    if (fileUpload != null)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            fileUpload.InputStream.CopyTo(stream);
            _buildingService.ImportPlanningInformationsAsync(stream.ToArray(), fileUpload.FileName);
            message = "Загрузка файла началась";
        }
    }
    return PartialView(T4.Admin.Views._PlanningInformationImportHistoryPartial, PreparePlanningInformationImporHistoryModel(filterDate, message));
}

private PlanningInformationImportHistoryModel PreparePlanningInformationImporHistoryModel(DateTime filterDate, string message)
{
    var model = new PlanningInformationImportHistoryModel();
    model.ImportStartedMessage = message;
    model.Imports = _buildingService.GetPlanningImports(filterDate).Result;
    return model;
}
```

Видим, что контроллер возвращает `_PlanningInformationImportHistoryPartial`, которая выглядит так:

```
@model ibZKH.Web.Models.Admin.PlanningInformationImportHistoryModel

    @if (Model.ImportStartedMessage != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>@Model.ImportStartedMessage</strong>
        </div>
    }

<div class="span10">
    @if (Model.Imports.Length > 0)
    {
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Документ</td>
                <td>Дата заливки</td>
                <td>Статус</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Imports.Length; i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Model.Imports[i].FileName</td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.Imports[i].ImportTime.ToShortDateString()
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Model.Imports[i].Status
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action(T4.Admin.DownloadPlanningInformationImportReport(Model.Imports[i].Id, Model.Imports[i].FileName))" title="Отчет о загрузке">
                            <i class="icon-download"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="@Url.Action(T4.Admin.DownloadPlanningInformationImportErrors(Model.Imports[i].Id, Model.Imports[i].FileName))" title="Детальный отчет об ошибках">
                            <i class="icon-download-alt"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <span class="label label-default">
            В выбранный день не было произведено импорта помещений
        </span>
    }
</div>
```

Если поставить точки останова, то все выполняется правильно, как и должно быть. 
Все заполняется, и все отображается, **но**!

### Результат выполнения данной операции отображается через 2-3 минуты!

На всех остальных представлениях, которые есть в этой модели (да и в любых других) - все отображается быстро, практически моментально. Но это представление имеет странный глюк. Почему так происходит и как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скорее всего проблема в строке

```
model.Imports = _buildingService.GetPlanningImports(filterDate).Result;
```

У вас эта страница где-нибудь рендерится как отдельный блок?
Если она используется только для этого Ajax запроса, сделайте из ParvialViewResult полноценный **async Task «ActionResult»** и используйте await в этой операции.

Comment: метод `GetPlanningImports` отрабатывает за доли секунды, практически моментально. Или скорость не влияет?

Comment: Попробуйте закомментировать строку для тестирования, будет ли после этого выполняться быстрее? Вообще, частичные представления в Asp.net mvc 5 не предусматривают использование асинхронных методов.

Comment: @DenisBubnov проблема в том, что он запускает асинхронную операцию. А получение `Result` заставляет дожидаться ее окончания.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не помогло. Сделал как Вы и сказали, заменил на такую строку: `model.Imports = new PremiseImportResultDto[0];` Все равно работает долго.

Comment: @DenisBubnov а файл какого размера загружаете?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, размер файла *106Кб*. Метод вызывается асинхронно и в этом месте нет тормозов, по всему проекту любая долгая работа метода вызывается асинхронно, а результат - сообщение о том, что что-то выполняется. Везде работает быстро, даже в тех местах, где загрузка длится пол часа.

Comment: @DenisBubnov а через отладку загрузку файла делали?

Comment: @Fakemind да, делал. Загрузка асинхронна, я не жду результата :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, убрал `_buildingService.ImportPlanningInformationsAsync(stream.ToArray(), fileUpload.FileName);` и результат стал отображаться сразу.